# Query executed through PDO return less records than from PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

## Query 1.

I try to run it using PHP:

```php
<?php

$pdo = new \PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=postgres', 'postgres', 'postgres');

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'CHAC TECHNOLOG*' as alias
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERY LIGHTING SALES DE?T*'
) m 
JOIN (
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 
ORDER BY ie_clean;
SQL;

echo $sql . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

And I have next output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'CHAC TECHNOLOG*' as alias
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERY LIGHTING SALES DE?T*'
) m 
JOIN (
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 
ORDER BY ie_clean;

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alias] => CHAC TECHNOLOG*
            [ie_clean] => CHACTECHNOLOGICO\
        )

)
```

Only one record (it is wrong).

But when I try to run it directly in PostgreSQL, this query returns two records. It is correct result.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qNZY5SauB87na2pWf8uwxm/0

## Query 2.

It is similar query, but now I moved part of condition from `WHERE` to `SELECT` section:

```php
<?php

$pdo = new \PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=postgres', 'postgres', 'postgres');

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('CHAC TECHNOLOG*', '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') as alias
  UNION
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('KINDERY LIGHTING SALES DE?T*', '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')
) m
JOIN (
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\' as ie_clean
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE m.alias
ORDER BY ie_clean;
SQL;

echo $sql . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Output is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('CHAC TECHNOLOG*', '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') as alias
  UNION
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('KINDERY LIGHTING SALES DE?T*', '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')
) m
JOIN (
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE m.alias
ORDER BY ie_clean;

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alias] => CHACTECHNOLOG%
            [ie_clean] => CHACTECHNOLOGICO\
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [alias] => KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDE_T%
            [ie_clean] => KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT
        )

)
```

Two records! It is correct result.

Postgres returns two records too (it is correct):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSv1Tg9YJMgfUUhn7urFyF/0

## Question

I thinked that problem was with tailing slash in `'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\'`, but I has rechecked it, and as I see it is correct.

Why Query 1 return only one record from PHP. Is it bug of PDO or I do something wrong?

**UPD**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78534

Comment: The `.` string concat operator does not belong within a PHP heredoc string. The first SELECT section is missing an `alias`. And if in any way possible, do the glob to SQL placeholder substitution in PHP, not in SQL. Your PDO setup lacks the exception option.

Comment: Could be your PDO fetch mode. Have you tried `print_r($stmt->fetchAll());`? i.e. `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`

Comment: @mario "The first SELECT section is missing an alias" - it is ok for postgres. "The . string concat". Sorry, it was defected copypaste from mc, edited.

Comment: @EternalHour Yes, I has tried, but it has no effect for count of records

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset.

Comment: @EternalHour Dataset is contained in query (two rows)

Comment: I have an impression that I've seen a similar question before. But I cannot find it :(

Comment: @mnv could you provide your testing environment like php and pdo version etc?

Comment: @John PHP 7.3.9, PostgreSQL 10.10, php_pgsql version 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: Like other ppl said. Try to use prepared statements and see the result. Paste the error here if any and we may continue with the help.

Comment: @DilyanTrayanov Prepared statements dont helps if I try to replace `'?'`. Query returns 0 records with `\'` : https://gist.github.com/mnvx/616d84801aaa4db5fbeb0bad5df85876#file-gistfile1-txt-L15  and 2 records without `\'`: https://gist.github.com/mnvx/616d84801aaa4db5fbeb0bad5df85876#file-gistfile1-txt-L43

Answer (score 3):

The root of your problem is a question mark inside one of REPLACE function.

The actual query that reaches the server looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'CHAC TECHNOLOG*' as alias
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERY LIGHTING SALES DE?T*'
) m
JOIN (
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '$1', '_'), ' ', '')
ORDER BY ie_clean;
```

So PDO replaces the **?** to **$1** and the second part of query becomes invalid which leads to 1 row

You have to bind the value somehow(what is tricky and might won't work) or change you query work with ?.

Try this to see the actual result (not recommended, a lot of talks about this option here)

```
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

[image: here is a PostgreSQL log]

Comment: Why PDO may replace '?' to '$1' if this symbol contains in string? I has tried to set `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);` but it have no result. First query still return one record instead of two.

Comment: And why PDO dont replace `'?'` to `'$1'` in Query 2?

Comment: Which php version/driver do you have? Also if you don't believe me try to replace ? sign with for example & in both places and you should get positive result. Why it does the replacing - for me it looks like bug for now. It shouldn't and it doesn't do this with first ? sign btw

Comment: Yes, replacing of '?' to '-' helps. But also helps replacing `'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\'` to `'CHACTECHNOLOGICO'` without replacing `'?'`. You may reproduce it too. Im confused... https://gist.github.com/mnvx/b24ac480be377b106b4e8538a27ba0ae

Comment: You gist returns 2 rows.  But in your gist you removed two slashes, yeah. What's the goal?

Comment: My goal is to understand is this behaviour is bug of PDO or I do smething wrong.

Comment: Treating  '?' sign as a placeholder is a default behaviour in PDO. But if you try to bindValue/bindParam for it with '?' sign - it's not working also. So i think there is a bug in PDO which doesn't allow to use question mark as part of query, when the sign is alone(or wrapped in quotes)

Answer (score 1):

In conlusion, backslash will affect query generation in PDO.

I would said this is a bug 
or 
conflict between PHP and Postgresql policy.(see additional information)

In PHP PDO,

**expecting normal behavior**

```
--RAW QUERY
SELECT ?
--PHP parsed
SELECT ?
--Postgresql received
SELECT $1
```

```
--RAW QUERY
SELECT '?'
--PHP parsed
SELECT '?'
--Postgresql received
SELECT '?'
```

**unexpecting abnormal behavior**

```
--RAW QUERY
SELECT '?\'
  UNION
SELECT '?'
--PHP parsed
SELECT '?\'
  UNION
SELECT '?'
--Postgresql received
SELECT '?\'
  UNION
SELECT '$1'
```

Please compare next examples.
I will focus on next line two lines.

LINE A

```
SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\' as ie_clean
```

and LINE B

```
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')
```

**example1**

```
LINE A use double backslash  \\  
LINE B's ? will become $1
```

```
//RAW QUERY
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 

--PHP parsed \\ => \
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean  /* double became single */
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 

--Postgresql received  ? => $1
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '$1', '_'), ' ', '')
```

**example2**

```
LINE A use single backslash  \  
LINE B's ? will become $1
```

```
//RAW QUERY
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 

--PHP parsed  \ => \
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')


--Postgresql received ? => $1
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '$1', '_'), ' ', '')
```

**example3**

```
LINE A does not use any backslash 
LINE B's ? will become ?
```

> Question mark(?) **will not be changed** to $1 **without backslash** \

```
//RAW QUERY
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '') 

--PHP parsed
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO' as ie_clean
  UNION
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')

--Postgresql received ? => ?
...
  SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO' as ie_clean
  UNION 
  SELECT 'KINDERYLIGHTINGSALESDEPT' as ie_clean
) t ON t.ie_clean ILIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.alias, '*', '%'), '?', '_'), ' ', '')
```

**additional information**

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\\' as ie_clean
SQL;
```

PHP parse the above as ( **single \**)

```
SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean
```

found OUTPUT of the above line in postgresql is different according to version.

```
//v9.0.4 use \ to escape character
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean"
LINE 1: SELECT 'CHACTECHNOLOGICO\' as ie_clean

//v9.3+ treats \ as character
CHACTECHNOLOGICO\
```

Postgresql changed syntax of "\"

pdo_pgsql might not be updated accordingly.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you for interesting observation.